# MySQL/PHP AES Encryption and ODBC Conn. with Access

Tags: php, mysql, ms-access, encryption, aes

I recently changed a few fields in a PHP form to store encrypted fields using AES in a MySQL database. The same code is used to display the form results online through a web-based interface, so it works out great!

But! I was informed that another user connects directly to the database with Access via ODBC and sees only garbled info in those fields. Is there a way I can allow these fields to be shown fully in Access?

The encryption is AES and appears to be compatible with MySQL's AES_DECRYPT, though there are trailing "\0\0\0\0" after each value in the query.

Comment: Can't you call `AES_DECRYPT` on Access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Access table should have the LONGBINARY (OLE Object) data type.